# How do I profile F# script

Tags: f#, profiling

I am learning F# by automating few of my tasks with F# scripts. I run this scripts with "fsi/fsarpi --exec" from command line. I am using .Net core for my work. One of the thing I was looking for is how to profile my F# script. I am primarily looking for

1. See overall time consumed by my entire script, I tried doing with stopwatch kind of functionality and it works well. Is there anything which can show time for my various top level function calls? Or timings/counts for function calls.
2. See the overall memory consumption by my script.
3. Hot spots in my scripts.

Overall I am trying to understand the performance bottlenecks of my scripts.

On a side note, is there a way to compile F# scripts to exe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/) for any benchmarking tasks (well, micro-benchmarks). Since it's a statistical tool, it accounts for many things that hand-rolled benchmarking will not. And just by applying a few attributes you can get a nifty report.

Create a .NET Core console app, add the BenchmarkDotNet package, create a benchmark, and run it to see the results. Here's an example that tests two trivial parsing functions, with one as the baseline for comparison, and informing BenchmarkDotNet to capture memory usage stats when running the benchmark:

```
open System
open BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes
open BenchmarkDotNet.Running

module Parsing =
    /// "123,456" --> (123, 456)
    let getNums (str: string) (delim: char) =
        let idx = str.IndexOf(delim)
        let first = Int32.Parse(str.Substring(0, idx))
        let second = Int32.Parse(str.Substring(idx + 1))
        first, second

    /// "123,456" --> (123, 456)
    let getNumsFaster (str: string) (delim: char) =
        let sp = str.AsSpan()
        let idx = sp.IndexOf(delim)
        let first = Int32.Parse(sp.Slice(0, idx))
        let second = Int32.Parse(sp.Slice(idx + 1))
        struct(first, second)

[<MemoryDiagnoser>]
type ParsingBench() =
    let str = "123,456"
    let delim = ','

    [<Benchmark(Baseline=true)>]
    member __.GetNums() =
        Parsing.getNums str delim |> ignore

    [<Benchmark>]
    member __.GetNumsFaster() =
        Parsing.getNumsSpan str delim |> ignore

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    let summary = BenchmarkRunner.Run<ParsingBench>()
    printfn "%A" summary

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

In this case, the results will show that the `getNumsFaster` function allocations 0 bytes and runs about 33% faster.

Once you've found something that consistently performs better and allocates less, you can transfer that over to a script or some other environment where the code will actually execute.

As for hotspots, your best tool is to actually run the script under a profiler like PerfView and look at CPU time and allocations caused by the script while it's executing. There's no simple answer here: interpreting profiling results correctly is challenging and time consuming work.

There's no way to compile an F# script to an executable for .NET Core. It's possible only on Windows/.NET Framework, but this is legacy behavior that is considered deprecated. It's recommended that you convert code in your script to an application if you'd like it to run as an executable.